# How to create a dependency property for a textbox

Tags: wpf, textbox, dependency-properties

I am very new to wpf as well as Dependency properties.How can we create a dependency property for a TextBox that sets the text property of the TextBox from any other class in the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `DependencyProperty` for that.

`DependencyProperties` are normally used when you create a [Custom Control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11248415/643085), which is not what you're doing here.

In your case, you need to use [Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx), which is a feature of WPF that allows you to "link" or more precisely "bind" the Values of most properties of UI elements to values in some properties of some other classes. For example:

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
```

Class:

```
public class Person
{
    public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

I suggest you read up on basic WPF concepts in [WPFTutorial.net](http://www.wpftutorial.net/)