# Setting default ControlTemplate for WPF CustomControl

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, controltemplate

I have designed some WPF CustomControl and I wrote a ControlTemplate for them, and i assigned ControlTemplates to those controls through styles :

for Example:

```
 public class BootstrapText : TextBox
 {
     protected override void OnLostFocus(RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
          // ...
     }

     protected override void OnTextChanged(TextChangedEventArgs e)
     {
         // ...
         base.OnTextChanged(e);
     }

     public static readonly DependencyProperty RegexProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Regex", typeof(string), typeof(BootstrapText), new PropertyMetadata(null));

     public bool IsValid
     {
        // ...
     }

     public string Regex
     {
       // ...          
     }

     static BootstrapText()
     {
         DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(BootstrapText), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(BootstrapText)));
     }
 }
```

and ControlTemplate (Actually Style) is Something like:

```
 <Style TargetType="Controls:BootstrapText" BasedOn="{StaticResource FontBase}">
     <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
     <Setter Property="Width" Value="240"/>
     <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"></Setter>
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FEFEFE"/>
     <!--<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>-->
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="Controls:BootstrapText">
                 <Grid>
                     <Border Name="container" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#ccc" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                         <ScrollViewer Padding="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                     </Border>
```

While i have no `x:Key="SomeKey"` in the style. this style will affects all `BootstrapText`s.

This is Good. But I have another problem. Somewhere in a Form, I want to Style these Controls and Set some Margin and Padding for them but leave the defaults as they are. but my Control will be disappeared !!!

I think twice styling will hides the default style.
In the standard Controls like `TextBox`, `Button`, ... whenever we write some style, everything is good and style simply sets our properties.

I think, I must assign my ControlTemplate directly to the CustomControl Because i must get ride of this Styling process. but I don't know how ?

Comment: Try "UserControl". It's very convenient to use in this case. Read more: [Custom vs User control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247708/custom-vs-user-control)

Comment: @mm8 answer was great. this is good to know the secrets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A default `Style` for a control should be define in a `ResourceDictionary` called `generic.xaml` and this `ResourceDictionary` should be located in a folder called `Themes` at the root of the assembly in which the control is defined by default.

These names are by convention so just move your `Style` to `Themes/generic.xaml`.

Comment: Thanks !!! That was great. so if i had multiple controls; should i place whole styles in this file (`generic.xaml` i mean). does it possible to put them in separate files ?

Comment: You can use the MergedDictionaries property to merge several different resources into generic.xaml.

Comment: MergedDictionaries not working for me. I added this into generic.xaml : `<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries><ResourceDictionary Source="Panel.xaml"/></ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>` but i have runtime error: `Cannot locate resource 'panel.xaml'` (Panel.xaml is in Themes folder; i tried to change it's location and test it again but it still not working)

Comment: I have found that Relative source doesn't accepted in generic.xaml. I replaced my resourceDictionary to `<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Bootstrap;component/Themes/Panel.xaml"/>` in generic.xaml and its working now.