# Why the Dependency Property can no be use in usercontrol?

Tags: wpf

I want to make a brand new button, so that I create a usercontrol inherits Button to do this.
Here is the XAML:

```
<Button x:Class="Uploader.PropertyButtonControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Uploader"               
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:Svg2Xaml;assembly=Svg2Xaml"
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.6*"></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0.4*"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border Width="{Binding Path=ActualHeight,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="{Binding IconBackground,Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <s:SvgShape Source="{Binding IconSource,Mode=TwoWay}"></s:SvgShape>
                </Border>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ButtonTitle,Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="#575757" Text="{Binding ButtonContent,Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBlock>
                <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" BorderBrush="#cecece" BorderThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed" Name="Bo"></Border>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="Bo" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

And here is code-behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Uploader
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for PropertyButtonControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class PropertyButtonControl : Button
    {
        public PropertyButtonControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public SolidColorBrush IconBackground
        {
            get { return (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(IconBackgroundProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IconBackgroundProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IconBackground.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IconBackgroundProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IconBackground", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(PropertyButtonControl),null);



        public ImageSource IconSource
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(IconSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IconSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IconSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IconSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IconSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(PropertyButtonControl), null);



        public string ButtonTitle
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ButtonTitleProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonTitleProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ButtonTitle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonTitleProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonTitle", typeof(string), typeof(PropertyButtonControl), null);



        public string ButtonContent
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ButtonContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ButtonContentProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ButtonContent.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonContentProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonContent", typeof(string), typeof(PropertyButtonControl), null);


    }
}
```

If I used it in a page as:

```
<local:PropertyButtonControl IconBackground="Red" ButtonTitle="123" ButtonContent="456"></local:PropertyButtonControl>
```

After the program ran ,the content do not showed and color not changed? It seems is the binding problem.
But what's wrong with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `UserControl` which is not adapted for a *brand new button*.
You should rather use a `CustomControl`. [Read this if you want more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247708/custom-vs-user-control).

Here is how we do:

Create a new class inheriting from the `Button` control in a separate file *PropertyButtonControl.cs*:

```
public class PropertyButtonControl : Button
{
//No need for Constructor and InitializeComponent

    public SolidColorBrush IconBackground[...]
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconBackgroundProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IconBackground", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(PropertyButtonControl), null);

    public ImageSource IconSource[...]
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IconSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(PropertyButtonControl), null);

    public string ButtonTitle[...]
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonTitleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonTitle", typeof(string), typeof(PropertyButtonControl), null);

    public string ButtonContent[...]
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonContent", typeof(string), typeof(PropertyButtonControl), null);
}
```

Create a ResourceDictionary containing the XAML template in a separate file *PropertyButtonControl.xaml*:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:view="clr-namespace:StackTest.View">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type view:PropertyButtonControl }">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.6*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="0.4*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border Width="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                            Grid.RowSpan="2"
                            Background="{Binding Path=IconBackground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=view:PropertyButtonControl}}">
                    </Border>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                               Text="{Binding Path=ButtonTitle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=view:PropertyButtonControl}}"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="1"
                               Foreground="#575757"
                               Text="{Binding Path=ButtonContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=view:PropertyButtonControl}}"/>
                    <Border Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Grid.RowSpan="2"
                            BorderBrush="#cecece"
                            BorderThickness="1"
                            Visibility="Collapsed"
                            Name="Bo"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Bo" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Add this resource dictionary to your `App.XAML` resources:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="View/PropertyButtonControl.xaml"/>
         </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Enjoy your control:

```
<local:PropertyButtonControl IconBackground="Blue" ButtonTitle="123" ButtonContent="456"/>
```

I put all my files in a folder named `View`. You must adapt it to your own structure.

Comment: OK，I always obscure the customcontrol and usercontrol, now I think I know what the difference between them. Thank you.