# Set a dependency property from a method which calls a property changed callback

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have a strange problem with my WPF control. Basically I have a control which presents modal content in front of my primary content. My control is a modification of my answer shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11234797/577417).

I have a `Bool` dependency property called `IsShown` which is used to hide / show the modal content. The property is defined like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsShownProperty =
    = DependencyProperty.Register("IsShown",
    typeof(bool), 
    typeof(ModalContentControl), 
    new UIPropertyMetadata(false, IsShownChangedCallback));
```

It has a standard .Net property wrapper like so:

```
public bool IsShown
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsShownProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsShownProperty, value); }
}
```

The property changed call back looks like this:

```
private static void IsShownChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ModalContentControl control = (ModalContentControl)d;

    if ((bool)e.NewValue == true)
    {
        control.ShowModalContent();
    }
    else
    {
        control.HideModalContent();
    }
}
```

The `ShowModalContent` and `HideModalContent` methods contain the logic to show and hide the modal content respectively.

I have this control in my window and the `IsShown` property is bound to my viewModel. I can press a button which invokes a command that changes a boolean property that is bound to the `IsShown` property of my control. The modal content is shown and hidden as expected.

My problem comes from the fact that the `ShowModalContent` and `HideModalContent` methods are public so that they can be called from code. What I want to be able to do is call `ShowModalContent`, for example, and when I query the `IsShown` property it should report the correct value (in this case true) E.G. If I was using a regular property I would have a backing field of type `Bool` which would be updated in the method. This field would then be returned by the property get statement.

But because my property is a dependency property I don't have access to a backing field. The only way I can update the value from the method is to set the dependency property through the .net wrapper but this stops my control from working (once the content is shown I cannot get rid of it again).

I thought this behaviour might be caused by setting the `IsShown` property in the method, which calls the property changed callback, which sets the `IsShown` property which calls.. but I remember reading somewhere that WPF protects against this scenario.

So how do I fix this problem so that my boolean dependency property reports the correct value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a little bit of thought (and some luck) I managed to figure out what the problem was. There were 2 things I needed to change in order to get this to work.

The first problem was that the `ShowModalContent` and `HideModalContent` methods were doing two things.

1. Setting the `IsShown` property.
2. Updating the state of the control.

This was a problem because changing the `IsShown` property calls the `IsChangedCallback` which calls either the `ShowModalContent` and `HideModalContent` methods which then change the `IsShown` property. I think `WPF` stops an endless loop occurring but even trying to manage this in code by caching the values was a major headache.

My moment of inspiration came when I realised that the *only* thing the public method should be doing is setting the property. My public methods now look like this:

```
public void ShowModalContent()
{
    IsShown = true;
}

public void HideModalContent()
{
    IsShown = false;
}
```

This then triggers the property changed callback which updates the state of the control.

My second moment of inspiration was when I realised my ViewModel wasn't accurately reflecting the state of the `IsShown` property and that this was being caused by the fact that apparently the default dependency property binding mode is `OneWay`. I simply updated my `DependencyProperty` definitions binding mode to `BindsTwoWayByDefault` and everything now works fine.

```
IsShownProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsShown",
    typeof(bool), typeof(ModalContentControl), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, 
        FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, 
        IsShownChangedCallback));
```