# How should selecting an item for edit and showing and edit popup be done in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF application that I am trying to keep as close to MVVM as possible. I have a class `TitlesModel : MappedViewModelCollection<TitleEditModel, Title>`, where `MappedViewModelCollection`, which has a property `public ObservableCollection<TViewModel> Items { get; set; }`, which is bound to a DevExpress `GridControl`. Each row in the control has an **Edit** and **Delete** button. When this button is pressed, I would like to bind the `TitleEditModel` for that row in the grid to a view that is a popup, modal window.

Do I 'tell' the main view model this, and let it instantiate, bind, and show a popup, or merely instantiate a popup, pass the row's `EditViewModel` to it and let it do it's own thing?

What is the conventional pattern for grid/detail view scenarios like this?

Comment: Hmmm I pick the second one. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#master_detail_scenario

Comment: [This may be of interest to you.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11234797/577417)

Answer (score 0):

This question recently came up in our company, and it's one where the lines of MVVM become very blurry. I haven't come across a clear statement yet.

Of the options you mentioned, the second one seems *more MVVM*, but your ViewModel becomes UI aware, which I'd avoid if I were you. Always try to keep up a unidirectional awareness chain (**View** *knows* **ViewModel** *knows* **Model**)

To solve this, we introduced `Interaction` interfaces and had instances generated via Dependecy Injection.This keeps the ViewModels 100% testable, because you can replace the editor with plain code in test scenarios.

Example:

```
public interface IEditor
{ 
    void Edit(object input);
}

public class EditorView : IEditor
{
    public void Edit(object input)
    {
        // open modal window, set DataContext
    }
}

public class EditorStub : IEditor
{
    public void Edit(object input)
    {
        // alter the properties of input that you want to simulate user interaction on
    }
}
```